# Adding element to nested array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a nested array. It is about user information. I need to take the age from the user and add it to my array. I have tried some code approch. Did not work.
Here is the Array

```
var userData = [
  {
    "key" : "user A",
    "value" : [
      {
        "id" : 1,
        "location" : "NYC"
      },
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "profession": "programmer"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

JS:

```
userData.value.push({"age" : 25})
```

I want to add the age afte id 2 object

Comment: `userData` is an array of objects, there is no property named `values`

Comment: `userData` is an array, but you're not treating it as an array. The object it contains as its only entry (at index 0) has a property called `value`, not `values`. *(Edit: You've changed that now so it's `value` in both places.)* So `userData[0].value.push({"age": 25});` Voting to close as typo/nonrepro.

Answer (score 5):

You have to access the first element of userData:

```
userData[0].value.push({"age" : 25})
```

Comment: yes changed it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Andreas You're right !

Comment: a question , if i have multiple user , meaning multiple obj, do i have to use forEach loop for it ?

Comment: @itsMe You have to use array.find to find the user to wich you want to push something into value: 

var userKey = "user A";
var found = userData.find(u => u.key === userKey);
found.value.push({ age: 25 });

Comment: Thanks a lot, In the application , the user will add the age from a input tag. I am using angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

you use `userdata[0]` to `push` value at last in `array object`

```
userData[0].value.push({"age" : 25})
```